# Authorization Policies/Gates for Laravel 5.3 web app consuming own API w/ Passport

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-passport, policies

Using Laravel 5.3 I've set up a web app that consumes its own API.  Authentication successfully handled by Passport.  Web app uses auth middleware in routes and Model Policies for authorization.  API routing uses default 'auth:api' token guard to control access.

I would like to use the same Policies in app/Policies for API authorization as well as the web auth, but I don't understand how.  Calls such as `$this->authorize('view', $model)` do not work.  I guess I need to pass the user from `Auth::guard('api')->user()` to the Policies somehow?

Any help would be appreciated!

Update:  Got it working.

Seems that even for the API calls Laravel was still using the user from the web guard to check against policies.  This user is undefined for API calls.  So I needed to tell Laravel that all API calls should use the api guard.

1. Create a new middleware with `Auth::shouldUse('api');` in the handle function.
2. Assign the middleware to the api section in the kernel.

Laravel will now use the api guard for all API requests.  Calls like `$this->authorize('view', $model)` will work in both web and api.

Answer (score 2):

Update: Got it working.

Seems that even for the API calls Laravel was still using the user from the web guard to check against policies. This user is undefined for API calls. So I needed to tell Laravel that all API calls should use the api guard.

Create a new middleware with `Auth::shouldUse('api');` in the handle function.
Assign the middleware to the api section in the kernel.
Laravel will now use the api guard for all API requests. Calls like `$this->authorize('view', $model)` will work in both web and api.

Comment: You don't happen to have your repo public anywhere do you? 

I followed your instructions and I'm still having trouble with Passport and Model Policies.

Comment: sorry, my project is on hold but will be migrated to laravel 5.5 in the next couple months and then published.  not sure if that will entail any changes to the authentication?  there might be a boilerplate or package out there that has better examples for 5.4/5.5

Comment: I have the same problem here and can't get it working - even with a fresh install. The policy isn't even being called.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `auth:api` middleware for routes with Policies