# Call to undefined method "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::can()"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

**Unable to find answers anywhere**

I am using Laravel 5.5 policy to restrict a user from listing properties that are not registered by the user (authenticated via API). 
I have two classes User and HostProperty. Additionally, I have registered a policy for the user to access their hosted property list by ID.

Here are my models.

The Main Problem is not able to call on controller method - which throws above error:

```
$authUser = auth('api')->user();
if ($authUser->can('access', $property)) {
              return response()->json(['success' => 'success']); 
            } else {
              return response()->json(['error' => 'error']); 
            }
```

**User.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User extends EloquentUser implements Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;
    use SoftDeletes;
    use AuthenticableTrait;
    protected $guarded=[];
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    //hosts relation
    public function hostproperty()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Hosts\HostProperty','user_id');
    }
}
```

**HostProperty.php**

```
namespace App\Models\Hosts;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class HostProperty extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $guarded=[];
    protected $hidden = [
        'user_id',
    ];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
    }
}
```

**HostPropertyPolicy**

```
namespace App\Policies\Host;

use App\User;
use App\Models\Hosts\HostProperty; 
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class HostPropertyPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    /**
     * Create a new policy instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function access(User $user, HostProperty $HostProperty)
    {return TRUE;
        //return $user->id === $HostProperty->user_id;
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Laravel\Passport\Passport;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use App\Models\Hosts\HostProperty;
use App\Policies\Host\HostPropertyPolicy;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        HostProperty::class=>HostPropertyPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
         Passport::routes();

    }
}
```

**HostPropertyController**

```
    use App\User;
    use App\Models\Hosts\HostProperty; 
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class HostPropertyController extends Controller
{
    public function listOneProperty($propertyId)
        {
            $authUser = auth('api')->user();
            $property=HostProperty::with('user')->find($propertyId);
            if ($authUser->can('access', $property)) {
              return response()->json(['success' => 'success']); 
            } else {
              return response()->json(['error' => 'error']); 
            }
    }

}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('listOneProperty/{propertyId}',  array('as' => 'listOneProperty.get', 'uses' => 'HostPropertyController@listOneProperty'));
```

Please note: I am calling from API - the above route is for API, I am not able to use the policy on the API routes. I keep getting the above error while calling this route.

I tried

```
$this->authorize('access', $property);
```

However, since API doesn't store login session the above could not be completed so I again tried with

```
$authUser = auth('api')->user();
$authUser->authorize('access', $property);
```

Does not work either. I have tried all I can but still, I cannot get it done right.

If someone has an example of using Laravel policy in API authenticated by Passport it would be helpful for anybody looking to get this done right.

With regards

Comment: Have you done a ```composer dumpautoload``` after adding the classes? The classmap needs to be updated in order to find the policy related to the model.

Comment: Yes i cleared config cache, dump-autoload, dumpautoload, most of the things

Comment: For some reason you were right half way through, my routes were cached soo badly i had to run everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like

```
$authUser = auth('api')->user();
```

is returning a query instead of a `User` model.

Please make sure that `$authUser` is a User model before calling `->can()`

Comment: I tried with  $user=User::find(1);  Still returns the same error

Comment: Have you tried to use ```$this->authorize('access', $property);``` More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization#via-controller-helpers

Comment: I am using API, the authorize method is only useful for web routes I believe. I used that too, I have mentioned it above, it keeps returning unauthorize when I use that

Comment: Since API authentication is done using passport tokens, I dont think it will take the current authenticated user.

Comment: Here is a related post that may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799974/authorization-policies-gates-for-laravel-5-3-web-app-consuming-own-api-w-passpo

Comment: Yes Thank you .. The above stackoverflow answer worked for me. I had to create a new middleware and use Auth::shouldUse('api');  on every API calls for user to be available. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> However, since API doesn't store login session the above could not be completed so I again tried with

Authentication is typically handled by middleware in Laravel. If you're using Passport, you should be able to use the `auth:api` middleware to authenticate requests, as long as you're sending the correct Authorization header and token.

Try changing this

```php
$authUser = auth('api')->user();
```

to this

```php
$authUser = auth()->user();
```

And add the auth middleware to your route:

```php
Route::get('listOneProperty/{propertyId}', 'HostPropertyController@listOneProperty')
     ->name('listOneProperty.get')
     ->middleware('auth:api');
```

---

If you're consuming the api from your own web views and you want it to work with the current session, check out the *Consuming Your API With JavaScript* section of the Passport docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript